# How to create high memory usage on web page for testing purposes

Tags: javascript, html

just for debugging purposes, I would like to artificially push the memory consumption of a webpage - and I dont know how to achieve this with as few lines of javascript as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
const x = new Uint8Array(1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1).fill(255); // 1GiB
```

Comment: thank you Jonathan! :) just curious - was there any intention for the "const"? It seems to work with or without or with "var" as well.

Comment: @Mick No specific reason for `const` I just personally prefer to use it for values that I don't intend on changing. Feel free to use whatever you please :)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no such option in chrome dev tools, but you can try to do it manually for example this code will take approximately 4 MB

```
const data = new Array(1000000).fill('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
```